# One way data binding with Angular 1.5 working like two-way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I've read two blog posts : The [first](https://toddmotto.com/one-way-data-binding-in-angular-1-5/) says that it works and prove it with a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/wauana12). The [other says](http://jslancer.com/2016/02/19/demystify-angularjs-15-one-way-data-binding/) it works only with primitives.

EDIT after @estus response : now I make a copy because sorting is not an immutable function. The problem is different : **change in the controller is not reflected in the View with One-way**, but it is with Two-way.

I've worked on it and [also made a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicorama/m3ngw7uz/2/). My 1-way data-binding works like a two-way with objects - but correctly with primitive. It works when I use a ng-click that makes a $digest(), but not directly at the controller creation. What is wrong ?

Parent :

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <users-component users="users"></users-component> 
    <button ng-click = "check()">Check current users in Parent Ctrl</button>   
</body>
```

JS :

```
function UserCtrl($scope){
    console.log('Component users at the controller start :', this.users);
    this.sorting = function(){
        this.users = angular.copy(this.users).sort();
        console.log('Component users after sorting :', this.users);
    };

    //Change does not appear on View with one-way, but does with Two-ways
    this.users = angular.copy(this.users).sort();
    console.log('users in component after controller creation', this.users);
}

angular.module("demo", [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.users = ['John', 'Jim', 'Albert', 'Luc', 'Sheldon'];
  $scope.check = function(){
    console.log('Application Ctrl : current users', $scope.users);
  }
})
.component("usersComponent", {  
   template: '<ul><li ng-repeat = "user in $ctrl.users">{{user}}</li></ul>' 
    +'<button ng-click="$ctrl.sorting()">Sort users in Component Ctrl</button>',
   controller : UserCtrl,
   bindings:{
      users : '<'
   }
});
```

Notice that the exemple I show up also requires a button and `ng-click()` to modify the View.

Answer (score 2):

One-way binding isn't an issue here, it may work as advertised for both primitives and objects.

The problem is caused by [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array.

`this.users` in `usersComponent` scope and `$scope.users` in `AppCtrl` scope refer to the same object. Once it is sorted with `this.users.sort()` (`this.users = ...` doesn't do anything here), it is modified in both scopes. To change this behaviour, modify a copy and not the original object:

```
function UserCtrl($scope){
    console.log('Component users at the start :', this.users);
    this.users = angular.copy(this.users).sort();
}
```

Comment: Ouch, immutable... NOT. Still have a problem related to the same question.

Comment: @NicolasZozol One-way binding looks ok to me, at least in modern browsers http://jsfiddle.net/21fx2s3x/ . Please, clarify what kind of behaviour you expect from it.

Comment: The users should be sorted at the beginning of the App. We need to click on the 'Sort users' to show.